# Show $\left|\mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n}\right)-\mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_{n}\right)\right| \leq \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a finite measure space.

(i) Show $|\mu(A)-\mu(B)| \leq \mu(A \Delta B),\forall A,B\in\mathcal{A}$.

(ii) Assume $\left(A_{n}\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} ,\left(B_{n}\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq\mathcal{A}$ with
$\mu\left(A_{n} \Delta B_{n}\right) \leq 1 / 3^{n}, \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$. Show $$\left|\mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n}\right)-\mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_{n}\right)\right| \leq \frac{1}{2}
$$

---

(i) Done!

(ii) I'm trying to use (i) to prove (ii). I think I have to aim for

$$
\left|\mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n}\right)-\mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_{n}\right)\right| \le ... \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu\left(A_{n} \Delta B_{n}\right) \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{3^n} = \frac{1}{2}
$$

After the first inequality above I want to use (i). But I can not figure out the manipulation needed to get $\mu(\bigcup_{n=1} A_n \Delta B_n)$. (?)

Comment: $|\mu(A)-\mu(B)|=|\int(\mathbb{1}_A-\mathbb{1}_B)\,d\mu|\leq\int|\mathbb{1}_A-\mathbb{1}_B|\,d\mu=m(A\Delta B)$

Comment: @OliverDiaz 
In the course we are not at that point of integrating. It should be possible to solve it without.

Comment: $$
\begin{align}
\Big((\bigcup_nA_n)\setminus(\bigcup_mB_m)\Big)\cup\Big((\bigcup_mB_m)\setminus(\bigcup_nA_n)\Big)&= \Big((\bigcup_nA_n)\cap(\bigcap_mB^c_m)\Big)\cup\Big((\bigcup_mB_m)\cap(\bigcap_nA^c_n)\Big)\\
\subset \Big(\bigcup_nA_n\setminus B_m)\Big)\cup\Big(\bigcup_mB_m\setminus A_m\Big)=\bigcup_n (A_n\Delta B_n)
\end{align}
$$ The rest is easy: $\mu(\bigcup_n(A_n\delta B_n))\leq\sum_n\mu(A_n\Delta B_n)$

Comment: Thanks! I was closer than I thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice $$|\mu(A)-\mu(B)|=|\int(\mathbb{1}_A-\mathbb{1}_B)\,d\mu|\leq\int|\mathbb{1}_A-\mathbb{1}_B|\,d\mu=\mu(A\Delta B)$$

One can prove thus also as follows:
$$|\mu(A)-\mu(B)|=|\mu(A\setminus B)+\mu(A\cap B)-\big(\mu(B\setminus A)+\mu(A\cap B)\Big)|\leq \mu(A\setminus B)+\mu(B\setminus A)$$

One the other hand:

$$
\begin{align}
\Big((\bigcup_nA_n)\setminus(\bigcup_mB_m)\Big)\cup\Big((\bigcup_mB_m)\setminus(\bigcup_nA_n)\Big)&= \Big((\bigcup_nA_n)\cap(\bigcap_mB^c_m)\Big)\cup\Big((\bigcup_mB_m)\cap(\bigcap_nA^c_n)\Big)\\
&\subset \Big(\bigcup_nA_n\setminus B_m)\Big)\cup\Big(\bigcup_mB_m\setminus A_m\Big)\\
&=\bigcup_n (A_n\Delta B_n)
\end{align}
$$ The rest is easy: $\mu(\bigcup_n(A_n\Delta B_n))\leq\sum_n\mu(A_n\Delta B_n)$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n}\Delta \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_{n}  \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n}\Delta B_n.
$$
Then
$$
\mu\!\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n}\Delta \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_{n} \right)\le \sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu(A_n\Delta B_n).
$$

Comment: How do one realise $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n} \Delta \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_{n} \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n} \Delta B_{n}$?

Comment: @Xenusi Following your idea, it is reasonable to guess that one needs to use the union bound.